# Spring AOP - Error Generating proxies

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, cglib

I'm using spring AOP's around advice to capture processing time of a transaction. I'm getting the following error during application startup

```
error creating bean "coreMessageResourceAccesor"
   Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class 
     [class org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor]: 
Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
   Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

I identified what the problem is with the help of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490022/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-web-servlet-mvc-annotation-de). But I cannot change coreMessageResourceAccesor bean to use setter based injection because its using a spring class & that class doesn't have no arg constructor

Below is the configuration for the bean

```
<bean id="coreMessageSourceAccessor"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor" >
    <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.context.MessageSource"
        ref="coreMessageSource" />
</bean>
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need really need to configure `MessageSourceAccessor` accessor as a bean, it's generally easier to instantiate it manually as required.  So rather than inject the `MessageSourceAccessor` into your beans, inject the raw `MessageSource`, and then wrap it in a `MessageSourceAccessor` as required (i.e. using `new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource)`).

You can then put the advice around the `MessageSource` rather than the `MessageSourceAccessor`, which will work better.  Also, `MessageSourceAccessor` will not itself add any significant processing time, it's just a thin wrapper around `MessageSource`.

Comment: Thanks skaffman. This is an existing application and MessageSourceAccessor bean is being injected into bunch of different classes, and i dont feel comfortable changing all other classes. I'm wondering if there is any other work around for this problem. Please advise