# can i use <http:auto-config=true> and <UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter> at the same time in spring security

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Anyone know can I use  and  at the same time in spring security.xml? currently , I am using UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter under  tag in xml.
But when I set the auto-config to 'true' and put @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") in controller class, I am getting exception like expecting contructor or args with no method.

How can I solve this problem?
thanks

Comment: It's possible. Please paste exception.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about using `auto-config`. It is more trouble than it is worth. Just add the configuration elements you want manually.

If you are getting an error about not having a null constructor, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490072/241990) is probably the reason. Always post your exception though.