# AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass when calling bean from axis2

Tags: apache-axis, aspectj, spring-aop

I am loading my spring bean file at start up. It contains following content:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect">
        <!-- @Before -->
        <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBefore"
            expression="execution(* org.server.RequestProcessor.create(..))" />
        <aop:before method="advice" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>


<bean id="serviceImplementation" class="org.server.RequestProcessor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="daoFactory"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="server">
        <ref bean="server"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now from services.xml, i have declared "serviceImplementation" bean as SpringBeanName. It's content is following:-

```
<parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier">org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringServletContextObjectSupplier</parameter>
<parameter name="SpringBeanName">serviceImplementation</parameter>
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">org.server.RequestProcessor</parameter>  
<parameter name="LoadOnStartup">true</parameter>

<operation name="create">
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
        <actionMapping>http://www.example.com/ManagementServices/create</actionMapping>
</operation>
```

So, when the "create" operation will be called. aspect class will try to intercept the org.server.RequestProcessor.create(..)

But i am not able to implement this, i am getting following error on server start-up:-

```
2012-07-26 14:25:28,616 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceImplementation' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/test-bean.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.server.RequestProcessor]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:561)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.server.RequestProcessor]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:488)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:363)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:361)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitConstructors(Enhancer.java:721)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:499)
        at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:201)
        ... 45 more
```

I am using spring-2.5.5.

Comment: I'm going to reference to a similar bug that I used to fix my bug:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490022/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-web-servlet-mvc-annotation-de

Comment: @K.C. Thanks!! indeed that's my problem too