# AspectJ annotation point-cut not being invoved (for any annotation type)

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, aspectj

I've been through a lot of stackoverflow questions and the [AspectJ docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) and there must be something trivial wrong in my implementation as I haven't found any red flags going through the examples and docs.

**Goal**

Define a custom annotation that works as a point-cut for a method call (apologies if the semantics are not right here, I hope the examples help).

**Code**

Please note I've change some class names to make them sound generic.

```
package com.example.so;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import java.util.HashSet;

@Aspect
public class CustomAspect {

    private final HashSet<String> instanceProperty;

    public CustomAspect(final HashSet<String> constructorArgument) {
        this.instanceProperty = constructorArgument;
    }

   /* @Around("execution(* com.example.so.IService..*(..))")
    public void beforeTransactionalMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        System.log.println("execution point-cut");
        pjp.proceed();
    }*/

    // @Before("@annotation(java.lang.Override)")
    @Before("@annotation(com.example.so.Custom)")
    public void around() throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("annotation");

    }
}
```

The aspect interface:

```
package com.example.so;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Custom{

}
```

Spring configuration

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="customAspect" class="com.example.so.CustomAspect">
        <constructor-arg ref="arg"/>
    </bean>
```

Aspect in use:

```
(...)
    @Override
    @Custom
    public void saveData(final Object data) {

      // this is being called

    }
(...)
```

The POM, just in case (both version 1.6.11):

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Behavior**

If I remove the comments on:

```
/* @Around("execution(* com.example.so.IService..*(..))")
    public void beforeTransactionalMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        System.log.println("execution point-cut");
        pjp.proceed();
    }*/
```

This gets called but whatever I do, I cannot get the annotation point-cut called, either with my custom annotation or others (this might be silly but I tried it anyway):

```
    //@Before("@annotation(java.lang.Override)")
    @Before("@annotation(com.example.so.Custom)")
    public void around() throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("annotation");

    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas, I believe all the configurations are there since the `CustomAspect` is in the context and active. I've added component tags before but I removed them because I didn't think they make sense in this scenario.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your annotation is missing some meta annotations. It isn't available at runtime (for this add the `@Retention` meta annotation) you also might need `@Inherited` and you might want to specify on which types the annotations can be applied.

Comment: Is the class in which `saveData()` method is implemented, a Spring bean?

Comment: @M.Deinum aren't those optional? I had them at some point.

Comment: @M.Deinum the reason I added the annotation for `Override` (which might be silly) was to check if the problem was with my annotation or annotations in general. I'm adding the Retention and target metadata, and testing again.

Comment: I will edit the question, no changes with the metadata. @PredragMaric, the other point-cut declared is for the same class (all methods within interface), it gets called.

Comment: Sorry for trivial questions, but it'll help eliminate the obvious things. Is `saveData()` intercepted with the pointcut that works (one that catches all)? And in the same scenario, with annotation pointcut, it doesn't work? I'm asking this because Spring AOP will only work for methods called through Spring proxies, meaning if, for example, you call `saveData()` from some method in the same class, it won't work.

Comment: @PredragMaric yes, the commented `execution` point-cut works fine. That's why I didn't think it is a spring context issue. Shouldn't the `override` annotation work?

Comment: If you use `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`, does it make any difference?

Comment: You are using a very old AspectJ version, can you try the current version 1.8.4 instead of the old 1.6.11 (from 2011)? Chances are that numerous issues of the then still pretty new `@annotation()` syntax have been fixed.

Comment: I will try, thanks. Also with `proxy-target` I now get CGLIB error which I think is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490022/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-web-servlet-mvc-annotation-de

Comment: In order to avoid making this an endless discussion you want to consider publishing a minimal, self-consistent project (optimally a Maven build) on GitHub for us to reproduce the problem. I cannot help but feel that we are missing important bits of information here.

Comment: I will try updating the version and if that doesn't work I will do so.

Comment: So? Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately publishing the project at work is impossible (firewalls, proxy policies). I need to do the POC from scratch at home and publish it from there.